# System.NullReferenceException Sitecore error

Tags: reference, null, sitecore, sitecore6

I am facing this issue while upgrading my Sitecore version from 6.5 to 6.6.

I have followed all the steps to install the packages and do the configuration changes but I keep getting this error instead of creating several new instances and installing the update again and again.

**When I click on the Presentation\Details\Device Editor\Controls\Add dialog** I get the following error

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Client
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.SelectRendering.SelectRenderingForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

I have been loosing my sleep over this for over a month. Any idea of how to approach this issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same strange errors after upgrade from 6.4 to 6.5. It turned out that I didn't make all changes to web.config and other config files.

I think you should check all upgrade steps once again and see if everything is correct, especially if configuration is correct and are dlls in correct version.

You could also install clean version of Siecore 6.6 and then compare files using eg. Kdiff.